# Как получить исходный код страницы в браузере c#

Tags: c#

Здрасте, мне нужно получить исходный код страницы любого сайта и найти кол-во тегов a в этом коде. Пишу так :

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("https://vk.com/");
                Regex regex = new Regex("<[a]");
                MatchCollection collection = regex.Matches(htmlCode);
                MessageBox.Show(collection.Count.ToString());
            }
```

Выдает мне некое число совпадений, но если вручную открыть код страницы и поискать через cntrl + f тег , то получается намного больше, чем вернуло в программе. Я посмотрел какую строку он вообще возвращает и он не совсем так выглядит как в браузере.

Comment: Уж давно твердят о том, что парсить сайты с помощью регулярок неблагодарная затея. Используйте [Anglesharp](https://anglesharp.github.io/) [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1049162/222542)

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, но делал как написано в документации прописал какой тег выбирать : var cellSelector = "a"; ( надеюсь правильно), но все равно выдает разные значения